# SQL Server's port is blocked

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows

Developed a Windows application that remotely accesses an SQL Server online. However, the client's ISP blocks port 1433. What are the other options to connect to SQL Server from the windows app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server should have a network utility where you can configure the port to be used. Contact your client's ISP to see which ports are open (they may even be able to open up 1433 for you) then configure the server to use that port.

In my install, you select: `"Start > All programs > Microsoft SQL Server > Server Network utility"`, select `"Enabled Protocols"` then `"TCP/IP"` and `"Properties"`.

From there you can set the default port to a more accessible one.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the port number that SQL Server runs under, to use a port that is actually open at the ISP.

Since 1433 is the default port for SQL Server, it is a common target for hackers. Some ISPs pick an arbitrary port number to obfuscate this. You may need to find what port number that is from them.

Another option is to use a [WCF Web Service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/LinqWcfService.aspx) hosted in IIS and have your windows app call this service.